# Mysql decimal: floor instead of round

Tags: mysql, decimal

In my MySQL database I have field DECIMAL(23,5), so 5 digits after decimal point. Now, when I will query like this:

```
UPDATE my_table SET my_decimal_field = 123.123456789 WHERE id = 1
```

And then I will fetch that record:

```
SELECT id, my_decimal_field FROM gijhars WHERE id = 1
```

I get this result:

```
+------+------------------+
| id   | my_decimal_field |
+------+------------------+
| 5733 |   123.12346      |
+------+------------------+
```

So, of course, MySQL is **rounding** these values, if they have more than 6 digits after decimal point. Is there any setting in MySQL, to **floor** these values instead of rounding?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fixed-point-types.html _When such a column is assigned a value with more digits following the decimal point than are permitted by the specified scale, the value is converted to that scale. (The precise behavior is operating system-specific, but generally the effect is truncation to the permissible number of digits.)_

Comment: Can't use http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_floor?

Comment: Yes I can, just curious if it can be done by configuration, because I need this behavior in the whole application.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the [doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fixed-point-types.html)

> When such a column is assigned a value with more digits following the decimal point than are permitted by the specified scale, the value is converted to that scale. (**The precise behavior is operating system-specific, but generally the effect is truncation to the permissible number of digits.**)

If that is not the case for your operating system, then you can handle this while updating with [truncate](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_truncate)

```
UPDATE my_table 
SET my_decimal_field = truncate(123.123456789, 5) 
WHERE id = 1
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/7630)