# ROUND IN SQL Works but for this case what to do in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, regex

I need to round the decimals like :

```
1.00 ->1.0
1.987->1.98
1.93-> 1.93
1.07->1.07
```

How to do this in mysql?

Comment: What is the rule that has `1.00` going to one decimal point but everything else to 2?

Comment: Would a value of 2.00 be returned as '2.00' or '2.0'? Is there a RULE, a conditional test, that can be used to make a determination. This is a simple case (despite your claim that it isn't). Is '1.00' being returned as '1.0' because this is the first row returned, because it's equal to 1, or because it is less than 1.04? Give us the rule.

Answer (score 2):

Here goes some documentation

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_round

Quick answer:

```
mysql> SELECT ROUND(1.987, 2); = 1.99
```

OR More what you are looking for

```
truncate(1.987, 2) = 1.98
```

From [Mysql decimal: floor instead of round](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14936261/mysql-decimal-floor-instead-of-round)

Comment: boss,  i need if 1.00 then 1.0 and if 1.07 then 1.07 means it's not simple case. try to get my point and answers please

Comment: Maybe a case statement would help? I think you'll need to evaluate based on each individual row.

Comment: @ShrikantGupta Why don't you answer [Gordon's question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17883327/round-in-sql-works-but-for-this-case-what-to-do-in-mysql#comment26115230_17883327) ?

Answer (score 1):

This only makes a difference if you are outputting the number (numerically, `1.0` = `1.00`).  So:

```
(case when format(num, 2) = '1.00' then '1.0' else format(num-0.005, 2) end)
```

The `-0.005` is to overcome the fact that `format()` rounds rather than truncates.

Comment: just asking - `case` is faster than `if` in one condition ?

Comment: @jaczes . . . Probably not.  I imagine they are compiled into similar constructs.  However, such micro-optimizations are usually a waste of effort and brain bandwidth when trying to make queries run faster.

Comment: +1.  or `FORMAT(TRUNCATE( num ,2),2)`. I suspect OP wants to '2.00' returned as '2.0', but this isn't specified. This solution meets the specification (at least until the specification is modified.)

Answer (score 0):

Just like that:

`SELECT if(NUMBER mod 1=0,ROUND(NUMBER,1),ROUND(NUMBER,2));`

eg.

`SELECT IF(1.00 MOD 1=0,ROUND(1.00,1),ROUND(1.00,2));` => 1.0

[more info](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_round)

Comment: boss, i need if 1.00 then 1.0 and if 1.07 then 1.07 means it's not simple case. try to get my point and answers please

Comment: try now - its crud but works !